How to create a command to jump the display to a given value in Excel?
I am building a chronogram in Excel that will be used to collect information of events and data across 50 years. The document is also for consulting purposes. This means that I am trying to make the document as easy to navigate as possible.
I have years on columns and locations on rows. Is there a way to ask excel to display a given year on the screen (via jumping or scrolling throught the sheet)? I am using freezing panes so the first column and rows are alwyas there displaying essential information.
Please see the picture attached.
So for example is there a command to which I can input the year I wanna see (in "Display Year") and then the spreedsheet moves to that range/column/cell?
Or is there a way to make the scroll of the window always move let's say 36 columns each time the scroll bar on the bottom is clicked?


To navigate on the worksheet as you requested, you need to handle the Worksheet_Change event. Based on the provided screenshot, it can look like this:

Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Address = "$D$4" Then
    Cells(13, 12 * (Target.Value2 - 1969)).Select
  End If
End Sub

I assume what 'D4' contains the year as a regular number (not Date).
As soon as the new year value has been entered to 'D4', the right pane scrolls to display the middle of the year at the center of the pane as well as it possible.
You need to restrict 'D4' values applying Data Validation or add the special code to the event handler subroutine.

Thank you. Sorry for asking, but how do I save the code in the console? In the macro panel it never appears listed.

Is your environment Mac?

Microsoft Windows

Press Alt+F11 to open VBA Editor. Double click on Sheet2 in Project Explorer Window. Copy/paste the text. Save the workbook as the macro-enabled workbook.

You can mark the answer as accepted if it helps.

How is it going?
